# What is the difference between embedded database and ordinary database like MySQL or Oracle?

Tags: database

What is the difference between embedded database and ordinary database like MySQL or Oracle?
and when should we use which?

Answer (score 8):

Long story short:

An embedded DB (like MS SQL Compact, SQLite, etc...) is integrated in the application you are developping or executing. Usually is a file which contains specific data structure to store data.

An "ordinary" DB like MySql or Oracle or MS Sql need a server to execute and store data. You have to install the application in locale or remote server to allow the right connection.

Using an embedded db you can execute software without installing a DB server.

Comment: For the question "when we have to use it", I'd suggest you to take a look here:
[when-to-use-an-embedded-database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108437/when-to-use-an-embedded-database)

Answer (score 0):

An embedded database is a database technology in which database management solutions are built into an application rather than provided as standalone tools. In many cases, this effectively "hides" the database management tools from the end user.

In ordinary Database you unlike embedded Db you need to install the standalone application and server as well to work with the Db